# How do you build the complex numbers from foundations?

Tags: complex-numbers

Id like to know how the complex numbers are derived from axioms. Most textbooks talk of them as starting from the complex plane. Is there a way to derive the complex properties from say the properties of fields or is there some peano axiom like system for complex numbers.

Comment: Which books "talk of them as starting from the complex plan"? The typical way to introduce them is by demanding a system which includes a number $"i"$ such that $\sqrt-1=i$ .

Comment: This is just out of my curiosity...

Comment: Algebraically, the idea is to define field operations on RxR such that Rx0 = R.  (That is (a,0) + (b,0) must equal (a+b,0)  and (a,0)×(b,0) =(ab,)).

Comment: Which axioms do you want to derive the complex numbers from, and in what sense?

Comment: @guest: I think that's his question, and I don't think a satisfactory answer has been provided yet. I think the question is interesting. In particular, can we word the axioms so that they don't include the concept of the modulus $|z|$ of a complex number $z$? In $\mathbb{R}$ we have the completeness axiom, and we can avoid talking about things like convergence of sequences (which is metric-dependent, and is how we might define completeness in an arbitrary metric space) by using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is ordered; but $\mathbb{C}$ lacks an ordering which is compatible with its structure.

Answer (score 5):

You can construct the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ then define complex numbers to be the set $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ equipped with component-wise addition 
$$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$$

and multiplication given by

$$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$$

Comment: Excuse my ignorance... but could you arrive at eulers theorem from this starting point??

Comment: Alex uses basic operations on complex numbers, no Euler here...

Comment: To jim : Which theorem of Euler are you referring to?

Comment: The one relating e, i, sin and cos....

Comment: @jim Yes you can, many books on complex analysis use this as a starting point and arrive at all the normal theorems. Conway's Complex Analysis book is one example

Answer (score 3):

Another way that has not yet been given, although it isn't so from first principles, is to "construct" the complex numbers as a quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$, where $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Then $1$ is the ideal $ 1 + \langle x^2+1\rangle$ and $i$ is the ideal $x + \langle x^2+1\rangle$. Multiply the first ideal by $a$ and the second by $b$ and add them to form a number, repeat with a separate $c,d$ and you get the [rules in the answer given by Alex](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1777131/252957). A little more work is needed, since the quotient ring must be a field like $\mathbb{C}$. To do this, you simply need to show that the ideal $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is maximal. This particular treatment is given in [Galois Theory, 2nd Edition by David A. Cox](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118072057.html).

The set of reals in this construction are all values $r + \langle x^2+1\rangle$ where $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Consequently the field $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

The proper statement for this is $R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle \simeq \mathbb{C}$, or that the two are equivalent up to isomorphism.

I am assuming here you are happy with the existence of $\mathbb{R}$ and at least reasonably comfortable with the concept of Rings and Ideals. If not, I like [Rings, Fields and Groups by Allenby](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rings-Fields-Groups-Introduction-Abstract-Algebra-Mathematics/dp/0340544406/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1462739906&sr=1-1) and [Classic Set Theory by Derek Goldrei](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0412606100/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) because it covers this from a set-theoretic perspective and is written in a style suitable for self study (full disclosure: I'm an OU student and have exchanged a few forum posts inside the OU with the author).

Answer (score 2):

The natural way to obtain complex numbers is Field extension, and $\mathbb{C}$ is [the only possible finite extension of reals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199630/a-finite-field-extension-of-mathbb-r-is-either-mathbb-r-or-isomorphic-to). Simply talking, each extension is obtained by inviting new numbers that extend the area of usage of our algebraic operations (seeking algebraic closure of the set). We have derived $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{N}$ by solving equation $x + a = 0$, then have derived $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ by solving $x*y=a$, then extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ (algebraic numbers) appear when we try to solve $x^n - a = 0$ and $\mathbb{R}$ with its irrational numbers is a closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ (as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and we can approach any irrational number with a sequence of rationals). Finally, $\mathbb{C}$ is derived from the solutions of equation $x^n + a = 0$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, according to the fundamental theorem of algebra (ok, the field of complex algebraic numbers, but we have already invented transcendentals in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: $\mathh R$ has tons of extensions apart from $\mathbb C$, the field of rational functions in any number of variables for instance. Are you referring to _finite_ extensions?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez  Yes, I'm sorry. Wrote it according to my memory in simple words.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I have corrected my answer.